# How to extract array from object in Javascript-react native

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo

I got below object from expo-image-picker-multiple, I want to get an array that doesn't include the "u, V ,W", from below since they are giving me bugs,  I only want to extract the objects as array and use it to display the image locations, or how can I make below so I can "array.map" to display the images, thanks.

```
   Promise {
     "_U": 0,
           "_V": 1,
     "_W": Array [

Object {
  "albumId": "278607672",
  "creationTime": 1676714592000,
  "duration": 0,
  "filename": "IMG-20230218-WA0000.jpg",
  "height": 1024,
  "id": "24561",
  "mediaType": "photo",
  "modificationTime": 1676714592000,
  "uri": "file:///storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20230218-WA0000.jpg",
  "width": 576,
},
Object {
  "albumId": "1028075469",
  "creationTime": 1676670585051,
  "duration": 0,
  "filename": "Screenshot_2023.02.17_22.49.45.051.png",
  "height": 1280,
  "id": "24560",
  "mediaType": "photo",
  "modificationTime": 1676670585000,
  "uri": 
  "file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot_2023.02.17_22.49.45.051.png",
   "width": 720,
      },
      ],
      "_X": null,
     }
```

Comment: You are missing an `await` or a `.then`.

Comment: Thanks @Abe, can you show me how in the answer, this is the function that generates the above.   const imagesCallback = (photos) => {      
    console.log(photos);  
      navigation.navigate('AddNewService', {photos: photos});
    
  };                 how do I use Await or .then in this function

Comment: Thank you Abe, I was able to fix it with your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Abe is right always need to `.then(function(result)).catch(function(err))` on a promise as the request is async. Otherwise you can define an async function within which you are allowed to use `await` to wait for the answer

```
yourFunction().then((answer)=>{console.log(photos); navigation[....]}
```

[see also](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining)